# Unknown format conversion into JSON

Tags: javascript, json

This is a successful response from a server

```
  "{\"url\":\"http://res.cloudinary.com/ddon9fx1n/q8k0z4etg8d6w.jpg\",\"id\":\"r9bfnzjq8k0z4etg8d6w\"}"
```

What kind of format it is? How can I convert it into a JSON?

Answer (score 0):

It **is** JSON.

If you parse it you will get a string … of JSON.

If you parse *that*, you will get an object.

```js
const json = '"{\\"url\\":\\"http://res.cloudinary.com/ddon9fx1n/q8k0z4etg8d6w.jpg\\",\\"id\\":\\"r9bfnzjq8k0z4etg8d6w\\"}"';

console.log("JSON", json);

const decoded_json = JSON.parse(json);

console.log("Decoded JSON", decoded_json);

const object = JSON.parse(decoded_json);

console.log("URL", object.url);
```

Comment: What are those "\" things? I need to do response.json() ?

Comment: @poimsm2 — Escape characters. See the *string* diagram at http://json.org/

Comment: @poimsm2 —  "I need to do response.json()?". Maybe. It depends on the libraries you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure.. I working in an ionic-3 app and when I do .json() It throws an error

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong based on your vague description of the code you are using and even vaguer description of the error.

Comment: I just did JSON.parse(response) instead of response.json() and It's working now :D